# Как сделать Фильтр для Товаров, в Django(oscar ecomerce)

Tags: python, django, filter, ecommerce

Требуется сделать фильтр на подобии [этого](http://www.dota2.com/store?l=russian#cat=3776899405).
В Oscar, насколько я знаю, этого нету (и в свободном доступе скорее всего тоже). Я немного пораскинул по этому поводу, и решил, что стоит взять метод сортировки товаров, который использует Oscar (от А до Я, по рейтингу и тд)source -pastebin.com/jC0NRVCC , и немного переделать его под атрибуты товаров. Но я не могу понять, как наследовать эти самые атрибуты для массива.

```
SORT_BY_MAP = {
   #CustomsType:Here Are Properties
    TOP_RATED: '-rating',

    TITLE_A_TO_Z: 'title_s',
    TITLE_Z_TO_A: '-title_s',
}
```

Нужно взять основной класс Атрибутов - то i.imgur.com/dwzlucW.png?1 о чем я говорю (чтобы основывать поиск нужным образом)? Или взять все товары, которые возвращает запрос [поиска](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnVme.png), и с ними уже как-то работать.

Проблема в том, что для меня `Django` и `Oscar` в новинку, и я не очень понимаю все эту сложную структуру.

Прошу, помогите мне с этой проблемой, уже мучаюсь несколько дней!
Спасибо!

Comment: @ Ну что ктонибудь поможет ? Или слишком сложный вопрос ?

Comment: по поводу сортировки - попробуйте такой вариант, в views.py где вы получаете данные из базы:


    - CLASS_MODEL - название вашей модели
    - field - название поля/полей - по которым сортировать


    CLASS_MODEL.objects.all().order_by(*field) - по возрастанию
    CLASS_MODEL.objects.all().order_by(*field) - по убыванию

Comment: @ivanK. - сортировка мне не очень подходит, я нашел где используется фильтр(поиск) для Solr - но опять же там структура почти одинаковая как и в Sort_by_map. И я не могу понять что она означает - ` OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS = {
    'fields': OrderedDict([ ('product_class', {'name': _('Type'), 'field': 'product_class'}),
        ('rating', {'name': _('Rating'), 'field': 'rating'}), ` точнее я не очень понимаю почему product_class - берется именно первым [Здесь](http://goo.gl/Wvmdv2) , а не [отсюда]( http://goo.gl/ov01bE ) , как мне тогда указать product_class от AbstractProductAttribute ?

Comment: Я пробовал сделать что-то подобное ` ('product.attr.size', {'name': _('Size'), 'field': 'small'}),` но я так понимаю это не то

Comment: @ivanK. поможете ? Я могу скинуть нужные классы - на PasteBin, если это поможет ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такс небольшой - апдейт, мне практически удалось добиться нужного эффекта [Результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJtch.png) - товар теперь фильтруется по опциям атрибутов, но проблема в том что - та форма которая используется - не подходит для отображений опций - значения атрибутов, по сути вместо options - должно быть либо 3 CheckBox'a либо 1 DropDown Menu(C 3мя опциями выбора) то есть Small Medium Large, а там вместо этого Option.
Собственно сам код - может кому то пригодиться !

```
    product_class = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
```

.

```
    def prepare_product_class(self, obj):
    attributes = obj.attributes.all()
    if len(attributes) > 0:
        return [product_class.type for product_class in attributes]
```

И собственно значение которые можно подставлять в product_class.:

```
    class Meta:
    model = ProductAttribute
    fields = ["name", "code", "type", "option_group", "required"]
```

Важно при этом обновлять индексы ! - [результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGUuT.png) в принципе почти такой же, значение - Size. Small,Medium,Large не отображает, я так понимаю это ввиду того что нету нужной формы кнопки - в HayStack, а вот как ее сделать не очень понятно ? - помочь не кто не хочет добить тему =) ? Или создавать уже отдельный вопрос по формам ?