# Как вывести значение в Print - внутри Def

Tags: python, django, print

Не могу понять - как вывести значение которое обрабатывается внутри `def` - пример

```
def weigh_basket(self, basket):
    weight = 0.0
    for line in basket.lines.all():
        weight += self.weigh_product(line.product) * line.quantity
    return weight
```

Тут я хочу вывести значение `line`, если просто добавлю - после `for line in basket.lines.all():` `Print(line)` - то результат не выводиться, еще хотел бы уточнить, что все я это делаю в Django(oscar), таких проблем я не наблюдал в простом приложении питона, но здесь оно просто не выводит - как быть?

Comment: Что значит *"результат не выводится"*? Куда должен выводиться: лог, http-ответ?

Comment: @jfs Желательно чтобы он выводился суда http://i.imgur.com/X49mesv.png?1 - Console,

Comment: вы показали `access.log`. Думаю достаточно в `sys.stderr` печатать, чтобы django в какой-нибудь лог записала бы сообщения: `print('hello log', file=sys.stderr)` (на Питоне 2: `print >>sys.stderr, 'hello log'`). Или [стандартные возможности logging модуля использовать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#using-logging).

Comment: @jfs Я уже пробовал так делать(через Print>>sys.stderr(), результата 0 - так же пробовал через loggin, все-равно не выводит, только если там есть реальная ошибка(выводит)

Comment: @jfs - есть идеи как это решить ? Я это все проделываю в Oscar Django, простые приложения Python такой результат не дают.

Comment: Если пройти по ссылочке из предыдущего комментария, то там показан простой пример как использовать logging и как его настроить в контексте django.

Comment: @jfs - Я конечно возможно что-то делаю не так - но http://i.imgur.com/35LyK4F.png?1 , добавив Logger - Ничего не выводит `def weigh_basket(self, basket):  weight = 0.0
        for line in basket.lines.all():
            logger.error('Something went wrong!'+line)
       `

Comment: Что происходит если в этом месте `1/0` вставить? `logging` здесь работает абсолютно также как в любом другом django приложении, как описано по ссылке: в `settings.py` подкрутить по потребностям `LOGGING` словарь.

Comment: @jfs Я добавил в Settings Logging(Как там указанно), 1/0 не вставлял, я даж поменял класс в котором тестирую - на ( `class SearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):`
)  тот что отрабатывает - выбранные facets( Фильтры [категорий](http://pastebin.com/24TLYXNw) ) `for facet_kv in self.selected_facets: 1/0 ` если тут добавляю 1/0 Результата не какого, если до `for`, то выводит ошибку, но значение опять же не выводит - почему ?

Comment: Цель `1/0` увидеть что код исполняется и исключения видны в логе. Если вы не видите `ZeroDivisionError` после добавки 1/0, то бессмысленно дальше двигаться.

Comment: @jfs - да ZeroDivision Не выводит - если поместить его внутри for facet_kv, а вот если до, там где `selected_multi_facets` , то выводит - и как тогда быть чтобы вывести значение, внутри цикла For ?

Comment: Если до цикла выводит, а внутри нет — это значит что соответствующая коллекция пустая и тело цикла не исполняется, например `for anything in []: 1/0` — здесь `[]` это пустой список и `1/0` никогда не исполняется.

Comment: @jfs - так все разобрался -ивправду было пусто, теперь выбрал(chekBox) и ошибка начала появляться. и теперь через Print Даже выводит значение - ! спасибо, разобрался  !

Comment: Вы можете [добавить свой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (может это поможет кому-нибудь в будущем).

Comment: @jfs - спасибо еще раз, а другой вопрос - я давно создал тему про фильтры в oscar django - [stack](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456121/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-djangooscar-ecomerce) - но так особо и не получил даже комментариев - не поможете ? я бы не прочь просто понять как эти самые формы [фильтров](http://pastebin.com/24TLYXNw), доработать для атрибутов(товаров).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что коллекция была изначально пуста(по этому и ничего не выводило), ибо oscar(django) наполняет ее непосредственно - при использовании, в моем случае это был `Chekbox(field)` - и при его нажатии, значение начало передаваться в простой Print(внутри цикла) и выводиться! спасибо jfs что помог разобрать !